# Mutt: setting the maximal line length

Tags: mutt

Some mails don't break lines when they reach a certain length,
which makes them a pain to read in Mutt.  Mutt will wrap them, of
course, when they reach the end of the window, but can I set the
maximal length to something shorter than the width of the terminal
window?

Comment: Does this help? http://askubuntu.com/questions/65598/how-can-i-get-mutt-to-stop-making-vim-insert-line-breaks-every-few-characters

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For mutt's internal pager, that's controlled by the [`$wrap` mutt variable](http://www.mutt.org/doc/manual/#wrap).

```
set wrap=80
```

to wrap at column 80.

```
set wrap=0
```

to revert to wrapping at the width of the terminal. See also the [`$markers` option](http://www.mutt.org/doc/manual/#markers) for visual indications of wrapped lines and [`$smart_wrap`](http://www.mutt.org/doc/manual/#smart-wrap) to decide whether to wrap at word boundaries or not.

(at the `:` prompt or in `~/.muttrc` or in macros).